# Accesing the id attribute of the select tag from jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking for a way to access the id attribute of the select tag from jquery.

say i have a select tag on the form : form.php

```
<select id="testid">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

from jquery I can access the option value as `$(this).attr("value")`. But `$(this).attr("id")` gets undefined.

By giving the option tag some id attribute values it works. But, is there a way around to access the id of the select tag thru `$(this)` object

Thanks for any help

Comment: some of the code can help us add your html and js code, thx.

Comment: Try `$(this)[0].id` if its still undefined, the element probably doesn't have an ID. Like @vchakoshy said.. we need code.

Comment: Inside an event handler `this` will point to the element on which the event is bound to.
You need to clarify on which event you are trying to get that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying within `change` event of `select` it will look like:

```
$('select').change(function() {

    // here 'this' point to select

   console.log( $(this)[0].id );

   //OR simply

   console.log(this.id);

})
```

But `$(this).attr('id')` should also work.

If your `$(this)` point to `option` then try

```
$('select').has(this).attr('id');
```

OR

```
$(this).parent('select').attr('id');
```

Comment: i tried $(this).parent('select').attr('id'); but its not working.

Comment: Im sorry it works. There was something wrong in the code which was causing this not to work. Thanks @thecodeparadox for your help

Answer (score 2):

May be `this` in `$(this).attr("id")` pointing to `option` element.

Try this,

```
var id;
if(this.tagName === 'option'){
    id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
}
else{
   id = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$(this)[0].id
```

or

```
this.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this!

```
<select id="testid">
<option class='option' value="1">1</option>
<option class='option' value="2">2</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#testid").change(function(){
var option = [];

$("option.option:selected").each(function(i){// this will filter the selected id

option[i] = $(this).val();
});
alert(option);
});
});
```